# How to redirect the user to a product page (node) after payment is made?

Tags: redirection, commerce

How to redirect the user to a product page (node) after payment is made?

I'm using the Commerce Express Checkout module. That's why in the Shopping cart can be just one product.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you improve your question by following the advices in the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in a custom module to override your current destination page with a redirect.

```
<?php

function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) { 

    $items['current/checkout/path'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
        'page arguments' => array('new/checkout/path'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
      );

}
```

## Update:

To use the above code, you'll have to create a module.

1) Create a directory to be used for this module, e.g. `/sites/all/modules/MYMODULE`

2) Create MYMODULE.info, e.g. `/sites/all/modules/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.info`. Paste the following into the file.

```
name = MYMODULE
description = "Module description."
package = Custom
core = 7.x
```

3) Create MYMODULE.module, e.g. `/sites/all/modules/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module`. Paste the following into the file.

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) { 

    $items['current/checkout/path'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
        'page arguments' => array('node/123'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
      );

}
```

4) Replace all instances of `MYMODULE` with your desired module name. Replace `current/checkout/path` with the current path of the checkout. Replace `node/123` with the new checkout path. Lastly, enable your new module.

This will tell Drupal to replace the current checkout page with a redirection to the new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer!
I do not understand how to write the url of node page to redirect.
Should I use token? My product page is /goods/NID

Comment: You'll need to use the actual URL, not its alias, e.g. `'page arguments' => array('node/NID'),`.

Comment: I have just one more question. How to tell Drupal 7 which NID to use?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. If you're asking how to implement the above, I've updated the question for you. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: When I use a code: 'page arguments' => array('node/NID'), should the user be redirected to the node display of that product after payment? It doesn't work for me. Each time the NID is different. I'm doing something not correct.

Comment: I've never worked with this module, so I cannot answer questions relating to module-specific behavior. All this script does is forward the page from one Static URL to another. If, in your case, the destination page is different every time, you will have to do a `page callback` to a custom function, which decides the destination page. Search for `hook_menu` to learn more on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a rule, based on the event 'checkout complete' / 'first paid in full'.

Comment: How would the rules conditions / actions look like?